# Derivative by definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative by definition of the following function:

$f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}\sin(x)$

I know that by definition:

$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{|x+h|}\sin(x+h)-\sqrt{|x|}\sin(x)}{h}
$$

But if I try to find the derivative at $0$ I get:

$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{|h|}\sin(h)}{h}=0
$$

which is not true because the derivative $DNE$ at $0$
because:

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} \cos x+\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{x}}, \ \ \ \ \ x>0 \\
\sqrt{-x} \cos x-\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{-x}}\ \ \ x<0 \\
\end{cases}$$

So how can it be that the derivative exists only when it is calculated by definition?

Comment: Your final expression for $f'(x)$ looks as if it has limits of $0$ as $x \to 0$ from above or below.  Combine this with the continuity of $f(x)$

Comment: You could make the derivative concise by taking $$\frac{d}{dx}|x|=|x|/x$$. Try evaluating the resultant derivative using a limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't say that the derivative does not exist.

Indeed,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{|h|}\sin(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\sqrt{|h|}\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=0\cdot1.$$

As the limit exists, this is the value of the derivative.

Comment: Just a comment to the OP: the first equality holds because both limits on the right exist. If $\lim g$ and $\lim f$ exist, then $\lim f\cdot g$ exists and is equal to $\lim f\cdot \lim g$

Comment: Yves, I edited my question.

Comment: @CodeNinja: when you modify a question after the fact, you should clearly indicate it, otherwise comments and answers can become nonsense.

Comment: I just clarified my intention.

Comment: @CodeNinja: you should clearly indicate the change.

Comment: @YvesDaoust are you suggesting CodeNinja mark the changed part of the question with "EDIT:" or the like? I thought the recommended practice on SE sites was _not_ to do that. Though I suppose I don't know if this site has its own particular conventions on the topic.

Comment: @DavidZ: I can't tell you what the policy is. This makes the pages incoherent.

Comment: A bit of intuition for why the function should have $0$ slope there:  $y= \sin(x)$ looks like $y=x$ at $0$.  So $\sqrt{|x|}\sin(x)$ looks like $\sqrt{|x|}x$.  When $x$ is positive, this is $x^{3/2}$, and when negative the reflection of that. The power rule shows that this has zero slope at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} \sin x, \ \ \ \ \ x\geq0 \\
\sqrt{-x} \sin x\ \ \ x<0 \\
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} \cos x+\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{x}}, \ \ \ \ \ x>0 \\
\sqrt{-x} \cos x-\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{-x}}\ \ \ x<0 \\
\end{cases}$$
But
$$\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{x}}\rightarrow 0, \ \ \ \frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{-x}}\rightarrow 0$$
for $x\rightarrow 0^+$ and $x\rightarrow 0^-$. Moreover, by definition of derivative:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\sqrt{|h|}\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=0\cdot1.$$

Comment: but it does not defined at $x=0$ so the derivative does not exist at that point (because you divide by $\sqrt{x}$)

Comment: @CodeNinja Not true. The derivative at $0$ is **defined** as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}$. That is the definition. The fact that $\sqrt{x}\cos x + \frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt x}$ is not defined for $x=0$ does **not mean** that the derivative does not exist.

Comment: I agree with @5xum. Furthermore, the two limits are equal.

Comment: @Mark, So I can I know when I can calculate the derivative by a formula (like the chain rule of something else) or that it can be calculated only by definition.

Comment: @CodeNinja, if $\exists$ $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ then $f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$. But beware: this is only a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Mark, is there any ground rule that I can say: "This function's derivative should by calculated using the derivative definition" or "Using the chain rule is sufficient for that function". Or should I say $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ so lets use the definition

Comment: @CodeNinja : Much of analysis is techniques to "sneak up on" a value, typically when straightforward evaluation fails.  When you try straightforward evaluation, your "chain rule" option, and that doesn't work because something is undefined, you will have to sneak up on the result by taking limits.  In this case, you can do the sneaking by way of the definition of the limit.  (... or by observing that the $f'$ you have is actually continuous through $0$, so you could just take $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f'(x)$.)